# Activityからフラグメントを取得するスマートな方法｡

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

スマホとタブレット､画面の縦､横で違うフラグメントを搭載したレイアウトを用いる場合で､なおかつフラグメントの数が違う(idが違う)場合にActivity側からレイアウトにあるフラグメントを呼び出すときに､普通なら､`findFragmentById()`でidを指定して呼び出しますが､上記のようなレイアウト構成の場合idがタブレットスマホ､画面の縦､横で違うので呼び出し方に工夫がいると思うのですが､何かいい方法はありませんか｡

すでに考えた方法として､コード上でスマホ､タブレット､画面の縦､横を判定する方法がありますが､あまりスマートではないので､もっとスマートなやり方があれば教えて下さい｡  よろしくおねがいします｡

Comment: idを変える理由って何かあるのでしょうか？

Comment: @fkm様
それぞれActivityに乗っけるフラグメントの数が違い､表示する内容も微妙にちがうので変えました｡ 例えば､タブレットの縦でフラグメントを2つ､横で3つのフラグメントを乗っけたとすると､たとえ同じidをつけたとしても､横のフラグメントは1つ余るので､結局新しいIdを付けなければならないと思うのですが